# A LINQ query that will check if a start time and end time is available

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

So basically, the user will reserve a time on a specific day. for example March 21, 2016 10:00 AM to March 21, 2016 1 PM. If another reservation is to be made, the system should not accept a time between march 21, 2016 10 AM to 1 PM since it's already reserved to another user. please help im at loss and kinda new on programming. I'm stuck with this query

```
public Boolean CheckExistingTime(string reason, string coursegrade, string section, DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    try
    {
        using (IHSEntities model = new IHSEntities())
        {
            var list = from sched in model.Schedules
                       where sched.Reason == reason && sched.CourseGrade == coursegrade && sched.Section == section
                       select new ScheduleList
                       {
                           scheduleid = sched.ScheduleID,
                       };
            if (list.ToList().Count > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

here is the design of the schedule table

[image]

```
I am using Entity Framework, so here is the complete Schedule Class



  using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Data;
    namespace Business
    {
        public class Schedule
        {
            public class ScheduleList
            {
                public int scheduleid { get; set; }
                public string coursegrade { get; set; }
                public string section { get; set; }
                public string reason { get; set; }
                public string date { get; set; }
                public string level { get; set; }
                public string adviser { get; set; }
                public string starttime { get; set; }
                public string endtime { get; set; }
                public string inputtedby { get; set; }
            }
            public List<ScheduleList> GetAllSchedule(DateTime date)
            {

                try
                {
                    using (IHSEntities model = new IHSEntities())
                    {
                        var list = from schedule in model.Schedules
                                   where schedule.Date >= date
                                   select new ScheduleList
                                   {
                                      scheduleid = schedule.ScheduleID,
                                      coursegrade = schedule.CourseGrade,
                                      section = schedule.Section,
                                      reason = schedule.Reason,
                                      level = schedule.Levels,
                                      date = schedule.Date.ToString(),
                                      inputtedby = schedule.InputedBy,
                                   };
                        return list.ToList();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }

            }
            public List<ScheduleList> GetAllToday(DateTime date)
            {

                try
                {
                    using (IHSEntities model = new IHSEntities())
                    {
                        var list = from schedule in model.Schedules
                                   where schedule.Date == date orderby schedule.starttime
                                   select new ScheduleList
                                   {
                                       scheduleid = schedule.ScheduleID,
                                       coursegrade = schedule.CourseGrade,
                                       section = schedule.Section,
                                       reason = schedule.Reason,
                                       level = schedule.Levels,
                                       starttime = schedule.starttime.ToString(),
                                       endtime = schedule.endtime.ToString(),
                                       date = schedule.Date.ToString(),
                                       inputtedby = schedule.InputedBy,
                                   };
                        return list.ToList();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }

            }
public Boolean CheckExistingTime(string reason, string coursegrade, string section, DateTime start, DateTime end)
        {
            try
            {
                using (IHSEntities model = new IHSEntities())
                {
                    var list = from sched in model.Schedules
                               where sched.Reason == reason && sched.CourseGrade == coursegrade && sched.Section == section && sched.starttime <= start && sched.endtime >= end
                               select new ScheduleList
                               {
                                   scheduleid = sched.ScheduleID,
                               };
                    if (list.ToList().Count > 0)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
            public ScheduleList GetSchedule(int id)
            {

                try
                {
                    using (IHSEntities model = new IHSEntities())
                    {
                        var list = (from schedule in model.Schedules
                                   where schedule.ScheduleID == id
                                   select new ScheduleList
                                   {
                                       coursegrade = schedule.CourseGrade,
                                       section = schedule.Section,
                                       reason = schedule.Reason,
                                       date = schedule.Date.ToString(),
                                       level = schedule.Levels,
                                       adviser = schedule.Senttoadviser,
                                       inputtedby = schedule.InputedBy,
                                   }).First();
                        return list;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }

            }
            public Boolean Delete(int id)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (IHSEntities model = new IHSEntities())
                    {
                        foreach (Data.Schedule sched in model.Schedules.Where(x => x.ScheduleID == id))
                            model.Schedules.Remove(sched);
                        model.SaveChanges();

                        return true;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
            public Boolean Update(int id, DateTime newdate)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (IHSEntities model = new IHSEntities())
                    {
                        var list = (from sched in model.Schedules
                                    where sched.ScheduleID == id
                                    select sched).First();

                        list.Date = newdate;
                        model.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Include your `Schedule` model please

Comment: There are 2 ways to achieve it, list the clashes or try and find the holes .. the way to find clashes would be where proposed start time is between existing start and end, or proposed end is between existing start and end.

Comment: The time ranges intersect if range1 starts before the end of range2, and ends after the start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
using (var model = new IHSEntities())
{
    bool result = 
     model.Schedules.Where(s => s.Section == section && s.CourseGrade == coursegrade
                                && s.Reason == reason)
                    .Any(s => (s.starttime >= start && s.starttime <= end) ||
                              (s.endtime <= end && s.endtime >= start));
    return result;
}
```

If there is any record where the starttime lies between start & stop *or* where the endtime lies between start & stop this will return true.

**Edit:** This will only work if you didn't save your endtime and starttime with the date part truncated of course, otherwise you'll need to do an extra check on the date. (But please don't remove the date part from them, then your date field shouldn't even be necessary)

Comment: ive added duplicate record with the same start time and end time, but still was inserted inside the database. i dont know where the problem lies now, :(

Comment: so i look inside that query, it was returning false all the time

Comment: @yomamasonice Better make it <= and >= instead, I forgot about exact duplicate times, updated my answer

Comment: i just tried this, the query still returns false and ends up inserting into the table

Comment: @yomamasonice That's weird, you're sure the datetime in database contains both the date and the time right? And that your start & end also contain full date and time?

Comment: yes, format looks like this 2016-03-11 20:00:00.000.

Comment: i just copied your code and replaced mine, then check what the return is returning

Comment: @yomamasonice There has to be something wrong with either your input or values in database. Maybe your Section, CoursGrade or Reason isn't passed correctly, but I'm pretty sure this code sample is correct

Comment: @yomamasonice To be sure, maybe test it without the `Where` clause or something, then it should be true, even if section, coursegrade or reason aren't right

Comment: I FOUND THE PROBLEM, i had a similar name ddlcourse, and ddlCourse. i mixed them up so my parameter was wrong! THANKS ALOT!

Comment: @yomamasonice At last, victory! :p

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. The only wrong is this condition

```
sched.starttime <= start && sched.endtime >= end
```

You need to detect if the two ranges (with inclusive start and exclusive end) intersect (overlap). The correct condition is

```
sched.starttime < end && sched.endtime > start
```

Also, although not critical, in this particular function you don't need the whole list of overlapping items, but just a check if there is at least one, which in LINQ is represented by `Any` method.

So you can use something like this:

```
var query = from sched in model.Schedules
            where sched.Reason == reason &&
                sched.CourseGrade == coursegrade &&
                sched.Section == section &&
                sched.starttime < end && sched.endtime > start
            select sched;
return query.Any();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the DateTime.Compare method in the .Net framework. This compares two instances of DateTime and returns an integer that indicates whether the first instance is earlier than, the same as, or later than the second instance. So it will essentially compare with the time part also which is what you need.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare(v=vs.110).aspx

If you add your schedule model I can write a query for you.

Comment: this might sound dumb. do you mean schedule table design?

Comment: Yes or the schedule class if you are using EF code first.

Comment: In your ScheduleList is it possible to change the dates to DateTime objects? this will have an impact on the answer.

Comment: Ofc! I just got lazy and wanted a certain format so i made it to string.